# call in for dinner

Tags: verbs

I'm new to this site, so forgive me if I go wrong at some point forming my request.

My question is whether it's correct to use the word "call in" in the following context.

**The kids ran home right after they got called in for dinner.** (I mean their mom called them through the window and said it was dinner time).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The usage is fine. You could also drop the 'in' and the sentence would mean the same. i.e. "The kids ran home right after they got called for dinner."

Comment: My mother just whistled.

Comment: While it's perfectly understandable, I would say that the use of "called in" in that context is unusual for British English.

Answer (score 2):

*Called in* is correct, and *called* is also correct as @Rome_Leader points out.

The word *were* sounds more correct to me (American) than *got*:

> The kids ran home right after they **were** called in for dinner.

Comment: Thanks very much, guys, for your corrections and remarks.